# Hash does not change even when data set is changed to another value

Tags: java, arrays, java-8, blockchain, hashcode

I have created simple blockchain program with java. Currently I'm generating a hash for the transaction dataset. When i am changing the dataset for transaction the hash is not getting changed

Firstly I have created a transaction class with transactionName, transactionID and transaction TimeStamp values. Currently transactionDate and transactionID are generated Automatically.

Here is the package MainNode.pkg;

```
import NodeData.pkg.TransactionClass;
import sun.util.logging.PlatformLogger;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 * @author melanrashitha
 * @date 11/12/19
 * @project BlockChainArchController
 */
public class MainNode {

        private int hash;
        private int prevHash;
        private TransactionClass[] transactionData;
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("MainNode");

    public MainNode(int prevHash, TransactionClass[] transactionData) {

        //Logger MainNode Transaction class init
        logger.log(Level.INFO,"Node HB Received");


        this.prevHash = prevHash;
        logger.log(Level.INFO,"Node prevHash loaded : "+prevHash);

        this.transactionData = transactionData;

        logger.log(Level.INFO,"Node HB Received");
        logger.log(Level.INFO,"Node transactionData loaded : "+transactionData);




        //Current Calculated blockhash calculated on current transaction data, prev hashcode
        logger.log(Level.INFO,"Node Hash Generating ");
        Object[] object = new Object[] {transactionData,prevHash};

        this.hash = object.hashCode();
        logger.log(Level.INFO,"Node Hash Generated  :  "+ this.hash);
        logger.log(Level.INFO,"Node HB Detached");
    }

    public int getHash() {
        return hash;
    }

    public int getPrevHash() {
        return prevHash;
    }

    public TransactionClass[] getTransactionData() {
        return transactionData;
    }
}
```

When the transaction data is changed it still displays same hash
value

Here are the log messages

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_212.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java "-javaagent:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=55843:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_212.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_212.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_212.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_212.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_212.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_212.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_212.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_212.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_212.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_212.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_212.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_212.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_212.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_212.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_212.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_212.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_212.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_212.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_212.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_212.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_212.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_212.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ant-javafx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_212.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/dt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_212.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/javafx-mx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_212.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/jconsole.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_212.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/packager.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_212.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/sa-jdi.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_212.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar:/Users/melanrashitha/Desktop/Desktop/stripe-payment-gateway-module/BlockChainArchController/out/production/BlockChainArchController MainNode.pkg.BlockChainMain
Nov 12, 2019 11:57:02 AM NodeData.pkg.TransactionClass <init>
INFO: Transaction HB Recieved
Nov 12, 2019 11:57:02 AM NodeData.pkg.TransactionClass setTransactionDate
INFO: Transaction Date Created : 15068497599682
Nov 12, 2019 11:57:02 AM NodeData.pkg.TransactionClass setTransactionID
INFO: TransactionID Created : 64c27bf9-d3e6-48bc-b2b5-d6cc10f62df7
Nov 12, 2019 11:57:02 AM NodeData.pkg.TransactionClass <init>
INFO: Transaction HB Detached
Nov 12, 2019 11:57:02 AM NodeData.pkg.TransactionClass <init>
INFO: Transaction HB Recieved
Nov 12, 2019 11:57:02 AM NodeData.pkg.TransactionClass setTransactionDate
INFO: Transaction Date Created : 15068523666838
Nov 12, 2019 11:57:02 AM NodeData.pkg.TransactionClass setTransactionID
INFO: TransactionID Created : 9796a6c7-9d74-404a-8434-9844c18e481a
Nov 12, 2019 11:57:02 AM NodeData.pkg.TransactionClass <init>
INFO: Transaction HB Detached
Nov 12, 2019 11:57:02 AM NodeData.pkg.TransactionClass <init>
INFO: Transaction HB Recieved
Nov 12, 2019 11:57:02 AM NodeData.pkg.TransactionClass setTransactionDate
INFO: Transaction Date Created : 15068528416745
Nov 12, 2019 11:57:02 AM NodeData.pkg.TransactionClass setTransactionID
INFO: TransactionID Created : 9469aa4e-70fb-4088-9261-a5274f4214fc
Nov 12, 2019 11:57:02 AM NodeData.pkg.TransactionClass <init>
INFO: Transaction HB Detached
Nov 12, 2019 11:57:02 AM NodeData.pkg.TransactionClass <init>
INFO: Transaction HB Recieved
Nov 12, 2019 11:57:02 AM NodeData.pkg.TransactionClass setTransactionDate
INFO: Transaction Date Created : 15068533175911
Nov 12, 2019 11:57:02 AM NodeData.pkg.TransactionClass setTransactionID
INFO: TransactionID Created : 1d179fc7-eb39-4c81-bfed-4afdb8579a8f
Nov 12, 2019 11:57:02 AM NodeData.pkg.TransactionClass <init>
INFO: Transaction HB Detached
Nov 12, 2019 11:57:02 AM MainNode.pkg.MainNode <init>
INFO: Node HB Received
Nov 12, 2019 11:57:02 AM MainNode.pkg.MainNode <init>
INFO: Node prevHash loaded : 1
Nov 12, 2019 11:57:02 AM MainNode.pkg.MainNode <init>
INFO: Node HB Received
Nov 12, 2019 11:57:02 AM MainNode.pkg.MainNode <init>
INFO: Node transactionData loaded : [LNodeData.pkg.TransactionClass;@5caf905d
Nov 12, 2019 11:57:02 AM MainNode.pkg.MainNode <init>
INFO: Node Hash Generating `enter code here`
Nov 12, 2019 11:57:02 AM MainNode.pkg.MainNode <init>
INFO: Node Hash Generated  :  41359092
Nov 12, 2019 11:57:02 AM MainNode.pkg.MainNode <init>
INFO: Node HB Detached
```

Comment: Can you provide an example? Your log file only contains one line of "Node Hash Generated". What are you doing that you think your hash code does not change?

Comment: Thank you cmoetzing This will Generated by following snippets

Comment: ``//Create Transaction data block
        TransactionClass[] transactionClassesDataSet = {new TransactionClass("0x01"), new TransactionClass("02x0")};

        TransactionClass[] transactionClassesDataSet2 = {new TransactionClass("00x3"), new TransactionClass("00x4")};


        //Create Genesis Block
        MainNode genesisBlock = new MainNode(001,transactionClassesDataSet2);``

Comment: https://ibb.co/3vKLvVz

Comment: Please update your question so other readers do not have to read all comments to understand your question.

Comment: Not a blockchain problem although , relates to java .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling `hashCode()` on an array, in your case `Object[] object`. And since arrays don't override the `hashCode()` method from the Object class you will get the result from the [`Object.hashCode()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode--) method. This method will not take into account the content of your array. So you will get the same hashcode of an array each time in your current JRE.

```
String[] data = new String[2];
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data)+" - "+data.hashCode());
data[0] = "abc";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data)+" - "+data.hashCode());
data[1] = "def";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data)+" - "+data.hashCode());
```

This will generate an output similar to this:

```
[null, null] - 705927765
[abc, null] - 705927765
[abc, def] - 705927765
```

As you see there is no change in the hashcode even thou we change its content. To fix this problem you use the [`Arrays.deepHashCode()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepHashCode-java.lang.Object:A-) method. It will return the hashcode based on the content of the array. Try it by running the following code:

```
String[] data = new String[2];
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data)+" - "+Arrays.deepHashCode(data));
data[0] = "abc";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data)+" - "+Arrays.deepHashCode(data));
data[1] = "def";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data)+" - "+Arrays.deepHashCode(data));
```

You will get the following output:

```
[null, null] - 961
[abc, null] - 2987935
[abc, def] - 3087268
```

Keep in mind that your `TransactionClass` class must override the `hashCode()` method to make it work. Also keep in mind, when you override the `hashCode()` method you might need to override the `equals()` method as well.